# How to get requests coming out of Riot/League client

Tags: fiddler, riot-games-api

Fiddler doesn't show outgoing API requests.
Using IFEO debugger shows localhost requests that are not usefull for me, I need actual domains.

Someone told me that client ignores windows proxy and i need application proxy but client has protection against it so there's even more to it.
Has anyone tracked lol/riot's requests before and know how to do that?

Comment: Games usually use UDP for traffic that requires low latency. Unless you have a socks proxy (instead of an HTTP(s) proxy like Fiddler) you will not be able to see such traffic as HTTP proxies can not handle UDP traffic.

Comment: @Robert what would be SOCKS equivalent of fiddler?